# Versus "Touchpad 7"

Tags: android, eclipse, touchpad

Eclipse does not recognise my Versus Touchpad 7 for debugging.
If I switch debugging off when I connect the Touchpad 7 to my computer (Vista) I am able to transfer files, but if debugging is on then my computer searches (unsuccessfully) for a driver.
I have a small Android phone that connects fine to Eclipse.
Thanks for any ideas.

Comment: And DO you have adb driver for your device? Do you by chance have 64-bit Windows?

Comment: Try it on linux. Vista.. LOL

Comment: My Vista is 32 bit.  I must have at least one driver for the Touchpad 7 as I can connect with it when debugging is switched off.  Windows' search for a driver when the debugging is switched on has not found anything.